# xpath text() returns "None" when the tag is @href

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract text contained within HTML tags in order build a python `defaultdict`.
To accomplish this I need to clean out all xpath and/or HTML data and get just the text, which I can accomplish with `/text()` , *unless* it's an *href*.

How I scrape the items:

```
for item in response.xpath(
    "//*[self::h3 or self::p or self::strong or self::a[@href]]"):
```

How it looks if I print the above, without extraction attempts:

```
<Selector xpath='//*[self::h3 or self::p or self::a[@href]]' data='<h3> Some text here ...'>
<Selector xpath='//*[self::h3 or self::p or self::a[@href]]' data='<a href="https://some.url.com...'>
```

I want to extract "Some text here" and "https://some.url.com"

How I try to extract the text:

```
item = item.xpath("./text()").get()
print(item):
```

The result:

```
Some text here
None
```

"None" is where I would expect to see: `https://some.url.com`, after trying various methods suggested online, I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this line to extract either text or `@href`:

```
item = item.xpath("./text() | ./@href").get()
```

Comment: I should have asked this question a long time ago. Thank you, this was so simple after all.. it's either of the two, I had thought about it but could not get it.